# How to get macro functionality in python?

Tags: python, macros

I am new to python and I need to create a list and fill it with data.
like.

```
list = [  {  1: "first",2:"second"} , { i:"first",ii:"second" } ]
```

Thinking to create macro for optimization.
like.

```
#define english { 1: "first",2:"second"}
#define roman { i:"first",ii:"second" }
list = [ english, roman ]
```

Is there anyway to create macro like functionality here ?

Function is not solving problem as it will call function but I need code replacement.

Comment: Why do you think you need "macro functionality" here? Why couldn't you use normal variables for `english` and `roman`? (Although note your roman dictionary is not valid Python in either version.)

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I just created a ex. n missed quotes. wanted to show my need of having dictionaries inside list. 
was thinking if I can replace dictionary with a variable name like macro.

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough:

```
english = { 1: "first",2:"second"}
roman = {"i": "first","ii":" second"}
# NB : don't use "list" as variable name, 
# it would shadow the builtin `list` type
langs = [english, roman]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should just create 2 separate dictionaries and put them in the list

```
english = {1: "first",2: "second"}
roman = {"i": "first","ii": "second"}
li = [english, roman]
```

I use li because list is a reserved word in python.
The quotes around the roman numerals are there because i and ii aren't defined variables, so it would be better to use strings

Comment: thanks for the reply. 
I missed quotes, wanted to show dictionary inside list :).

Answer (score 0):

There is very nice solution in form of python module, the `cogapp` module.

Here is an example `macro_test.py`:

```
#define english { 1: "first",2:"second"}
#define roman { i:"first",ii:"second" }
#[[[cog
#   import cog
#   english = { 1   : "first",  2   : "second" }
#   roman   = { "i" : "first", "ii" : "second" }
#   cog.outl("mylist = [ {0!r}, {1!r} ]".format(english, roman))
#   
#   ## something actually usefull:
#   import os
#   git_command         = "git log --pretty=format:'%H' -n 1"
#   release_git_version = os.popen(git_command).read()
#   ## Note how release_git_version string contains quote char at start and at the end
#   cog.outl("release_git_version = {}".format(release_git_version))
#]]]
#[[[end]]]

print("mylist = {}".format(mylist))
print("release_git_version = {}".format(release_git_version))
```

Then you run the preprocessor like this:

```
python -m cogapp -r macro_test.py
```

And because of `-r` option `macro_test.py` source is rewritten to:

```
#define english { 1: "first",2:"second"}
#define roman { i:"first",ii:"second" }
#[[[cog
#   import cog
#   english = { 1   : "first",  2   : "second" }
#   roman   = { "i" : "first", "ii" : "second" }
#   cog.outl("mylist = [ {0!r}, {1!r} ]".format(english, roman))
#   
#   ## something actually usefull:
#   import os
#   git_command         = "git log --pretty=format:'%H' -n 1"
#   release_git_version = os.popen(git_command).read()
#   ## Note how release_git_version string contains quote char at start and at the end
#   cog.outl("release_git_version = {}".format(release_git_version))
#]]]
mylist = [ {1: 'first', 2: 'second'}, {'i': 'first', 'ii': 'second'} ]
release_git_version = '340b5c2f85c7070f236161d14db07a74ab9abdcb'
#[[[end]]]

print("mylist = {}".format(mylist))
print("release_git_version = {}".format(release_git_version))
```

Very useful for code generation. Now when you run `macro_test.py` script there is proper output:

```
>python macro_test.py
mylist = [{1: 'first', 2: 'second'}, {'i': 'first', 'ii': 'second'}]
release_git_version = 340b5c2f85c7070f236161d14db07a74ab9abdcb
```

I have added `release_git_version` code bit to show usefulness, as other answers try to dismiss this question as nonsense.

Please note that generating code like this is not proper way to optimize for performance. Python interpreter still needs to parse the generated code. If you are using CPython then optimization usually goes by re-implementing bottleneck-code in C/C++.

`cogapp` also works nice with code in other languages, XML or JSON. More details are [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/).